# How do I find and delete large files from Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive

The company I work for uses Google Apps (currently the free edition). I am nearing my storage limits (1GB) for the associated Google Docs.

Is there a way to find the large files (non Google Docs format files) that I have uploaded to Google Docs? I don't see a way to filter files based on size. I am hoping to delete the larger files to free up some space for my account. I am aware that we can purchase more storage if we need it, but I want to try deleting some files before we consider purchasing more storage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer does not quite fit into webapps, but there it is. I don't know of any other way to get the info without custom code.

1. Go to Google Docs
2. Create a new Spreadsheet
3. Go Tools/Script Editor
4. Replace the empty function in there with the text from here: http://pastebin.com/2uRe6GR0
5. Save (give any name)
6. Press run (green arrow) button. You may need to do it twice and at some point it will ask you to authorize the script and then you may need to press it again. Basically get the script to run
7. Go back to your original empty spreadsheet and voila, it has the information you need with the biggest file at the top. Apparently, files in native Google Docs format show size as 0 and do not contribute to your quota.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. I knew there was some way to get this information using the GDocs API, but your answer got me there without me having to write any code myself.

Would the question/answer be more appropriate at Stackoverflow perhaps?

Comment: There are minor changes in API. I made some changes in your script and created second revision R02: http://pastebin.com/MsgEVt3u

Answer (score 5):

1. In the new Google Docs (in 2015), in the bottom left, you see the quota you use and the words  "buy more storage".
2. Hover over it, to see a popup with usage details about Google Drive, Gmail and Google Photos. Next to Google Drive there is a blue "i" icon.
3. Click on it to get **all** items in your drive, sorted by size.

By the way, I found Google removes files from folders when someone I shared it with tries to deletes them or containing folders from their drive. But the files are still eating my quota. So here how to find files not in folders that are eating quota: search for "is:unorganized owner:my-email-address@gmail.com", and either re-add those "lost" files or delete them from the drive.

Comment: Nice, but This doesn't show the **exact** filesize.

Comment: True, it rounds to KB or MB. For deleting the largest files, that is enough for me. For precision work, not. I would like to be able to search for large files in a folder, but that is completely impossible up to now.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available in Google Docs - it probably has been added after you looked for it, but here it goes for the reference: You can sort by file size, use the sort button in the upper right corner. Remember to select All items first.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the actual reference :)

Comment: I did not forget a reference: I described user actions needed for you to sort by size. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for solutions. Just go to [drive.google.com/drive/quota](http://drive.google.com/drive/quota) and you get sorted list by size. Did not find this solution posted here, so I hope its helps others.